# MYSQL syntax with WHERE clause added

Tags: mysql

I have a small syntax issue in my MYSQL query i cannot seem to fix, it seemed fairly straight forward, here is the query:

```
$dates = DB::getInstance()->select("             
    SELECT today.clicks AS clicksToday, today.spend_amount AS amountToday, 
       yesterday.clicks AS clicksYesterday, yesterday.spend_amount AS amountYesterday,
       week.clicks AS clicksWeekly, week.spend_amount AS amountWeekly,
       month.clicks AS clicksMonthly, month.spend_amount AS amountMonthly
    FROM
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE()) today
    JOIN           
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE()) yesterday
    JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE()) week
    JOIN        
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) month

    JOIN   WHERE spend_user_id='{$globId}'";
```

The issue is with this part: **JOIN   WHERE spend_user_id='{$globId}'";** $globId contains the users unique ID, if i take this line away it works fine but pulls ALL data, i really need it pulled using the ID, i cannot see exactly what i did wrong, any help would be appreciated.

**SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3c694/1

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: what is `JOIN WHERE...` supposed to do?  You didn't specify a table or provide a join condition.  Furthermore the column `spend_user_id` doesn't appear to exist anywhere in your queried tables so even if that's supposed to be a simple `WHERE` condition it couldn't possible work.

Comment: What you are looking for is UNION ALL not JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I would incorporate the `spend_user_id` filter into the subqueries:

```
$dates = DB::getInstance()->select("             
    SELECT today.clicks AS clicksToday, today.spend_amount AS amountToday, 
       yesterday.clicks AS clicksYesterday, yesterday.spend_amount AS amountYesterday,
       week.clicks AS clicksWeekly, week.spend_amount AS amountWeekly,
       month.clicks AS clicksMonthly, month.spend_amount AS amountMonthly
    FROM
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() AND spend_user_id='{$globId}') today
    JOIN           
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE() AND  spend_user_id='{$globId}') yesterday
    JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE() AND  spend_user_id='{$globId}') week
    JOIN        
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND  spend_user_id='{$globId}') month";
```